# Sharepoint designer 2013 gets access denied when saving .aspx page on Office 365

Tags: access-denied, office-365-developer, designer

The title says it all: I opened an Office365 site on Sharepoint Designer 2013 and then tried to edit some **.aspx** pages.  When trying to save, I get "Access Denied" error.

If I try to edit and save an **.html** page, I get no errors.  If I try and rename the .html page to .aspx I get acces denied.  So it seemds like editing and saving aspx pages is disabled somewhere.

I have made sure that: I am a site administrator and Run Custom Web Scripts was enabled last week from the Office 365 admin site

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is no support to edit pages via SPD anymore, not for Online version

[image]

Comment: How about making Office365 show html pages instead of downloading them?  Is there a way to do that in the new versions?

Comment: I'm not sure it help, we have very limited access on Online verion compared with On-prem